# Solving differential equation of the form $u_x=u^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is my second week of learning PDE's.
I have two equations,
$u_t=u^2$ and $y_t=3y^{2/3}$. 
I know how to solve $u_x=x$ but I can't figure out what to to with those. 
If you could give me a helping hand on how to solve the following PDE's and give a method of solving similar to them.
I'm still a bit confused because it is a new subject, please be respectful.

Comment: These are ODE's.

Comment: How do you solve $u_x=x$ ? Please show us.

Answer (score 2):

Since differentiation is performed with respect to one variable only (say, we can call it $x$, or $t$), the above-mentionned "PDEs" are actually ordinary differential equations of the form $$
y' = a y^b \, .
$$
These are [Bernoulli differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) which resolution can be tackled by change of variable. Resolution is straightforward if $b =1$, with solutions of the form $y(x) = ke^{ax}$ where $k$ is an integration constant. Otherwise, setting $u = y^{1-b}$ gives
$$
u' = (1-b) y' y^{-b} = a(1-b) \, ,
$$
with solutions of the form $u = a(1-b)x+c$. Finally, by setting $c = k^{1-b}$, solutions read
$$
y(x) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&ke^{ax} & & \quad\text{if}\quad b=1\\
&\left[a (1-b) x + k^{1-b}\right]^\frac1{1-b} & &\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Or alternatively you can just use separation of variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Integrate both members of

$$u^{-n}\,du=dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give you a complete answer. I just want to give you the common idea to solve equations like yours (and I leave it to you to fix the details). Let $f$ be a differentiable function to be determined later. You can write your first equation as
$$
f'(u)u'=f'(u) u^2.
$$
That is (by chain rule)
$$
[f(u(t))]'=f'(u) u^2.
$$
If you are able to find a function $f$ such that $f'(t)=1/t^2$, then your original equation becomes
$$
[f(u(t))]'=1.
$$
Now you can compute $f(u)$ by integration. If your $f$ is injective then you are done.
This is the case of your first equation. You can take $f(t)=-(1/t)$. The equation you have to solve is then
$$
(1/u(t)))'=-1
$$
which gives you
$(1/u(t)))=-t+const$. Hence $u(t)=1/(const-t)$.